# Can intel p965 chipset motherboard support a Q9400 processor?

Tags: intel-core2

Can intel p965 chipset motherboard support a Q9400 processor? In fact what's the best processor it can support.

Comment: please post make and model of the mainboard, rather than the chipset.

Comment: The motherboard is Acer FG965M, which I can't find any info about. I am running q6600 on that board though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fraid not, the motherboard only supports FSB 1066 MHz, the Q9400 requires 1333 MHz.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is limited to Core 2 Duo, doesn't quite stretch to Core 2 Quad.

[Link to specification page](http://www.intel.com/products/desktop/chipsets/p965/p965-overview.htm)

> Supports Intel® Core™2 Duo processor, Intel® Pentium® D processor, Intel® Pentium® 4 Processor with Hyper-Threading Technology (HT Technology)◊1, and all other Intel® Pentium processors and Intel® Celeron® processors in the LGA775 socket, with scalability for future processor innovations.